# função Angular.js para calcular idade

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Boa noite pessoal.

Em meu bd, eu armazeno a data de nascimento de clientes.

Eu tenho uma lista que apresenta:

nome | cpf | idade?

Como eu poderia pegar o dado armazenado no bd e usando o Angular.js ou php calcular a idade atual e preencher minha lista?

No caso, os dados são apresentados na lista estão assim:

**{{data.nome}} - {{data.cpf}} - idade????**

Apesar de conhecer muito pouco sobre Angular.js, aceitei o desafio de estudar e modificar alguns sistemas que antes eu fazia com JQuery. Até o momento estou gostando.

Comment: Você consegue exibir os dados "Nome, Cpf, Idade" fazendo uma query por padrão?

Comment: Consigo sim @Vanderson ... acho que até vou adivinhar oque você vai me sugerir... calcular pela query? rsrsrsrsr vou tentar isso... tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, usando um cálculo direto na query. Portanto, nem precisei criar alguma função JavaScript... foi rápido e prático!

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') - 
  DATE_FORMAT(data_nascimento,'%Y') -
  (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(data_nascimento,'00-%m-%'))
AS idade;
```

Retirado de http://www.profissionaisdaweb.com.br/calculando-a-idade-diretamento-na-query-9.jsp

Answer (score 6):

Você pode implementar uma função:

- Controller

```js
$scope.calcularIdade = function calcularIdade(nascimento) {
    // Obtém a idade em milissegundos
    var idadeDifMs = Date.now() - nascimento.getTime();

    // Converte os milissegundos em data e subtrai da era linux
    var idadeData = new Date(idadeDifMs);
    var idade = idadeData.getUTCFullYear() - 1970;

    return idade;
}
```

- HTML

  ```
  {{ calcularIdade(data.nascimento) }}
  ```

Note que esse código tem problemas de precisão. A margem de erro pode ser de algumas horas em alguns anos, ou durante o horário de verão. O recomendável é usar uma biblioteca para fazer isso de maneira confiável.